# NGINX-Proxy: Running multiple ports tied to different virtual hosts on one container

Tags: nginx, proxy, docker, port, containers

Using [Jason Wilder's NGINX-Proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy), is it possible to tie two or more sets of virtual hosts to individual ports on just one container?

What I'm thinking:

```
# start the reverse proxy
docker run -d -p 80:80 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock jwilder/nginx-proxy

# start a first container for http://tutum.test.local
docker run -d -e "VIRTUAL_HOST=tutum.test.local" -e "VIRTUAL_HOST=tutum.school.nationwide" -p 80:80 -p 3000:3000 tutum/hello-world
```

Where the first virtual host could be linked to a socket running on port 3000 in the code, and the second virtual host could be linked to the 8080 port and handle regular API calls.

Is that possible or would I be better served to just break the socket off into a separate docker container?

Answer (score 0):

After further examining the code I realized this is not currently supported. The best method I've found is to break the sockets and API into different containers.